# Reordering list fields in SharePoint 2010

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-api

I am trying to reorder list fields using the function below. But for some reason, after executing this function, when I go check the field order in the `List Settings`, it doesn't seem to have been changed.

I get the following as the result of the `ProcessBatchData`:

```
<Result ID="0,REORDERFIELDS" Code="-2130575323">
    <ErrorText>
        Fields have been added or removed since you began this editing session. Please refresh your view and try again
    </ErrorText>
</Result>
```

What am I missing here?

```
/// <summary>
/// Reorders the share point list fields.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="spWeb">The sp web.</param>
/// <param name="spList">The sp list.</param>
/// <param name="orderedFields">The ordered fields.</param>
private static void ReorderSharePointListFields(SPWeb spWeb, SPList spList, IEnumerable<string> orderedFields)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    using (var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(stringBuilder)))
    {
        xmlTextWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("Fields");

        foreach (string orderedField in orderedFields)
        {
            xmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement("Field");
            xmlTextWriter.WriteAttributeString("Name", orderedField);
            xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
        }

        xmlTextWriter.WriteEndElement();
        xmlTextWriter.Flush();

        const string rpcMethod =
            @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>  
                            <Method ID=""0,REORDERFIELDS"">  
                            <SetList Scope=""Request"">{0}</SetList>  
                            <SetVar Name=""Cmd"">REORDERFIELDS</SetVar>  
                            <SetVar Name=""ReorderedFields"">{1}</SetVar>  
                            <SetVar Name=""owshiddenversion"">{2}</SetVar>  
                            </Method>";

        SPList list = spWeb.Lists[spList.ID];

        string rpcCall = string.Format(rpcMethod, list.ID, SPHttpUtility.HtmlEncode(stringBuilder.ToString()),
                                       list.Version);
        spWeb.ProcessBatchData(rpcCall);
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically you are using this function from Alexander Brütt: http://www.alexbruett.net/?p=48 ? It would be easier to contact him directly and ask for help. In any case: Are you trying to reorder the fields in the **view**? Does it need to be done via an RPC call? Why not go the easy path and change the order on the view itself via `ViewFields`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on other examples I can find:

- [Reorder SharePoint list fields from code](http://www.alexbruett.net/?p=48)
- [Export, Import, and Update List Fields](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2007/11/export-import-and-update-list-fields/)
- [How to change the order of the fields on a SharePoint form using code](http://pholpar.wordpress.com/2010/02/05/how-to-change-the-order-of-the-fields-on-a-sharepoint-form-using-code/)

The only difference I saw with your code was that, before your `ProcessBatchData` call, you did not have:

```
spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
```

If adding that does not help, I would suggest capturing the string output from `ProcessBatchData` to find out what exactly went wrong.

Comment: I have tried `spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;` didn't affect anything. So I took it off.

Comment: Try putting it back when you change your code to capture the ProcessBatchData return value. When you have the return value, add it to your question above.